# Apache Cordova - windows app open pdf file

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am currently developing windows app using Apache Cordova. My app requirements is to view local pdf file inside the apps. My problem is i can't view the pdf file using inappbrowser plugin, so what plugin should i use to open the pdf file?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the cordova plugin [cordova-open](https://github.com/disusered/cordova-open). It opens audio, video, images and more with applications installed on the user's device.

Comment: this plugin not support windows 8.